Can't change rooms using Socket.io
I'm attempting to integrate a way to change rooms using a function I already have that edits my html.
Client.js
function changeRoom() {
    let previousChat = currentChat;
    currentChat = newChat;

    // Emit the 'changeChat' event to the server
    socket.emit('changeChat');


Server.js
socket.on("changeChat", (previousChat, currentChat) => {
    socket.leave(previousChat);
    socket.room = currentChat;
    socket.join(currentChat);
  });

It doesn't allow me to switch rooms what so ever. I already have a system using html to determine the channel I'm in however I can't seem to figure out the socket.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
